# getting 2 enters in reponse - jquery ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

i have created i login form using core php,but i have a problem in it that is i get 2 enter  in ajax response thats why my condition not match properly and my login form not working.

my HTML:

```
<div id="block">
   <form method="post" name="form">
        <ul>
          <li>Usename:</li>
          <li><input id="email" type="text"  name="un" size="25" required  placeholder="Email"  ></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>Password:</li>
          <li><input id="password" type="password" name="up" size="25"></li>
          <li><input type="button" name="submit" value="LOGIN" onClick="rr();"></li>
       </ul>
   </form>
  </div>
```

my js:

```
function rr()
{
var data={
        'un':$('#email').val(),
        'up':$('#password').val()

    }

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data:data,
        dataType:"text",
        url:"/panchayat/web/action.php?action=login",
        success:function(response)
        {
            if(response=='true')
            {
                window.location.assign("home.html");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("wrong credencials");
            }
        },
        failure:function(response)
        {
            alert("there is an error.");
        },      
        error:function(xhr, status, error)
        {
          alert("xhr.response");    
        }

        });
}
```

my php:

```
function login()
    {
        $q=mysql_query("select * from tb_login");
        $ft=mysql_fetch_array($q);
        $_SESSION['emailid']=$_REQUEST["un"];
        $_SESSION['pass']=$_REQUEST["up"];
        if($_REQUEST["un"]==$ft["Emailid"] && $_REQUEST["up"]==$ft["Password"])
        {
            $n="true";
        }
        else
        {           
            $n="WRONG USERNAME OR PASSWORD";
        }
        echo $n;
    }
```

there is two enter come with 'true' in response so that my condition in success part does not match.please help me to get rid off with these enters.thanx in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by two enters? do you mean double submission of the login request

Comment: Make sure that there are no spaces after the last curly braces

Comment: You're only checking to see if the login details are the same as the first row from tb_login.  This won't work for anyone other than the 1st user.

Comment: @ArunPJohny that means 'true[enterspace][enterspace]'.

Comment: @shadow no there are no spaces after the last curly braces.

Comment: @Archer: i am checking if the login details are present in database then user can login but if details are not match then show wrong credencials.

Comment: You're going to have to explain what [enterspace] means, because that's not a known term.

Comment: I'm not a PHP guy, so don't see any problem there, but the client side you can try `if($.trim(response)=='true')`

Comment: @Archer: [enterspace] means extra space create by pressing enter.when i eveluate response in console it shows 'true  '.just extra space after true.in add to watch console it shows these spaces as enter sign.

Comment: @ArunPJohny: thanx `$.trim` works fine.it removed the extra space thanx alot.

Comment: @Jay I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to remove the spaces from `response` using [$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

```
if($.trim(response)=='true')
```